# How Can I use the textbox value as a where clause in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have been doing this some time now. I have an anchor tag that opens a pop up modal and passes the dropdown value to that modal which I already accomplished.

Now In my modal, I need to use the value on the textbox which is hidden (but not for now) to a mysql query.

I'm thinking on how Can i put that value in textbox to a php variable.

Need help please.

Here's my javascript for the opening of modal.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#modalRegister').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var modal = $(this),
        datestart = $('#datestart').val();
            modal.find('#myVal').val(datestart);
})
</script>
```

Now my Modal

```
<div id="modalRegister" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align-last: center">Register</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" id="myVal" value=""/>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Im thinking of doing a query there to cast a table and put the results on that table. The where clause if `<input type="text" id="myVal" value=""/>`

Comment: Where do you make any request to the server to execute that SQL query?  You would include the value in that request.

Comment: Learn ajax: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: AJAX or FORM anyway you need to send it to a server

Comment: use form or ajax to send the values to server, in your case to php.

Comment: @David: I'm thinking of placing the query string on that page as well. It's like a native Php programming. I mean the query will be in the modal as well.

Comment: @Ima : I know the ajax, I just dont know the query to get the value. And Please if you are going to post something at least do some explanation. Remember that there's a time that you also become like me.....a starter

Comment: @Ligthers: It's not really clear what you mean by that.  Have you made any attempt at this?  Can you show that attempt and explain in what way it failed?  That may clarify your intent here.  Any way you look at it, in order to send that value to a SQL query you're going to have to make a request to the server.  Either a form post or an AJAX request.

Comment: @Ligthers: either you have to use Ajax to achieve this or you need to change in page modal to iframe modal.

Comment: @Ligthers: Sorry if it hurts. See man, if you know ajax, you should be knowing that you cannot execute php in a modal. "Now In my modal, I need to use the value on the textbox which is hidden (but not for now) to a mysql query." So do understand things and try something. If you already tried something, please tell us what you tried. somebody will help you for sure

Comment: @Ima No worries. I feel a bit ashamed myself hehehe but thanks for pointing out.